# Liferay change portal settings by file

Tags: liferay, cas

i'm working with liferay in a local machine, with CAS implemented

I changed the cas setting in the web like this:

```
Login URL   - http://localhost:8080/cas-web/login
Logout URL  - http://localhost:8080/cas-web/logout
Server Name - http://localhost:8080/cas-web
Server URL  - http://localhost:8080/cas-web/proxyValidate
```

Now is giving me **ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR** when i'm try enter, i tried modify the portal-ext.properties for change the  **cas.auth.enabled=false** but seems like liferay have more priority in the portal settings.

The last configuration that works for me was:

```
cas.login.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web/login
cas.logout.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web/logout
cas.server.name=localhost:8080
cas.server.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web
cas.validate.url=https://localhost:8443/cas-web/proxyValidate
```

how disable the cas login for i can enter into liferay portal without cas and change the setting into the portal?

Comment: What about changing the properties it in the database?

Comment: You changed from *https* to *http* and now get an error message that contains the three characters *SSL*. I wonder if that has anything to do with each other. Maybe http doesn't support SSL? (that being said, it's a long time since I looked at the documentation for setting this up, but it's a good assumption that a SSO system would require https)

Answer (score 0):

Just go to table portletpreferences and search for portlet id like '%cas%';
then copy the preferences column in notepad and search for xml tag  set the value as false and restart the server.
You will be able to see the normal login page.